# asgi config in Django

Tags: django, django-channels, asgi

I implemented a chat environment with Django chat channel and it works with asgi, messages are exchanged on my computer without any problem, but when I upload my project on host, it does not exchange messages, I am wondering should I config my passenger_wsgi or some configuration from my host?

**My asgi config:**
import os
import chat.routing
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
{
"http": django_asgi_app,
"websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
),
}
)
```

**My wsgi**
import os from django.core.wsgi
import get_wsgi_application from django.core.asgi
import get_asgi_application os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'zgalaxy.settings')
aplication = get_wsgi_application() `

**My passenger_wsgi**
from zgalaxy.asgi import application `

**My settings.py**
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'zgalaxy.asgi.application' `

Comment: I advise you to run logs of your server to see what cause the error for my server I use ` Ubuntu` I run this code to print the logs in order to investigate the problem `sudo journalctl -e`